# MVC AccountController Usermanager.createasync Identity 2.0 Not working when host in Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using MVC Identity in my project with **Database First Approach**,I have method which override the Default Identity to my custom Created Identity.It works only if i connect to localDB in web.config with connection string has shown below and its hits that override method **OnModelCreating**,but if i use server it not going to that function due to that i am getting exception kindly suggest.

```
 //If i use this connection string it works//

 <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="Data Source=kittyrythmDB;database=TestDB;integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser, MyRole, long, MyLogin, MyUserRole, MyClaim>
    {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("TestEntities")
        {
        }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Map Entities to their tables.
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        // Set AutoIncrement-Properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        // Override some column mappings that do not match our default
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.UserName).HasColumnName("Login");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
        }

    }
 //But if i use this connection string its not working 
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.TestDB.csdl|res://*/DAL.TestDB.ssdl|res://*/DAL.TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxx;initial catalog=TestDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Define "not working"? And what exception are you getting?